# Why does right-click->View Data on Entity not show all fields

Tags: outsystems

In OutSystems service studio (version 10.0.450.0), when I right click an Entity and Select "View Data", some of the columns are not displayed in the output.

Is this expected behavior or perhaps a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted on the [OutSystems forum](http://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/22034/entity-view-data-does-not-show-all-columns/?%28Not.Licensed.For.Production%29=#Post86382) and they responded that it is indeed a [bug](http://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/22034/entity-view-data-does-not-show-all-columns/?%28Not.Licensed.For.Production%29=#Post86585).